# Can't resolve all parameters for MeldunekEditComponent: (?) after injecting 'Params' to constructor

Tags: angular

my routes:

```
{
path: 'meldunki', canActivate: [Auth3Guard], component: MeldunekComponent, children: [

  {path: ':id', component: MeldunekDetailComponent},
  {path: ':id/edit', component: MeldunekEditComponent},
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: MeldunekListComponent},
]
```

},

the route: meldunki/21329/edit

when I add to my constructor instance of Params from angular/router:

```
constructor(
          private params: Params) {
```

}
angular throws an error: Can't resolve all parameters for MeldunekEditComponent: (?).

Does anybody knows where's the problem?

Comment: can you show the constructor for MeldunekEditComponent? Where is Params coming from?

Comment: Inject `private route: ActivatedRoute,` instead `Params` and use `this.route.paramMap`

Comment: it's this one: constructor(
          private params: Params) {
}

Comment: Params is not injectable. just inject the `route: ActivatedRoute` to access the router params.

Comment: are you trying to read the router parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get URL params, you need to initiate activated route module in your constructor. Use as it is follows

```
 export class ABC {
 id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
 constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

use activated route to get the params . use subscribe on route.params to listen to param changes

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

      constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
            const id = route.snapshot.params["id"];
            console.log("param id",id);
            //IF needed to subscribe
            this.route.params.subscribe(
            params => {
            console.log(params['id'];);
      });
  }
```